# Javascript Facebook post preview

Tags: javascript, facebook, post, preview

I have 2 text fields, one for description, another for a link to be shared to Facebook (manually after review).
I want to show the user what their combination would look like, when I share it to Facebook.

I can simulate the post textbox as it is on Facebook (link below), but 1) when they change it, it will be out of date, 2) the URL will not be processed and shown as on FB.

Is there some easy way to show the user what the data will be rendered like, when I take it and post it on FB page?

Can be done any way (popup, iframe, etc... )
Without the possibility for sharing, for rendering I would support my Page info.

Which means for my user:
Fill in the description and url, when I share it on my page, it will look like this.

I found a similar question, but it did not cover rendering of the links [Create a Facebook Post Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637223/create-a-facebook-post-preview)

Does anyone have experiences in the area?

UPDATE:

For better understanding I drew pictures of the flow. On the first picture you can see 2 textboxes for the user. Here he enters description and a link. On the second picture his data, combined with my static data, are rendered just like it would be on Facebook, if I posted it via my page.

[Picture 1 - User interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx0sS.png)

[Picture 2 - Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPHMK.png)

Comment: Do you have a demo for your code?

Comment: no, that is the point, it is easy to disassemble the facebook post div in browser and simulate the css of the description part in my own div, but I wanted to see how the link will be rendered on FB. And of course they can always make a change in the appearance. That's why I am looking for some kind of Facebook endpoint that will show me 'yeah, this is what it would look like if you take the data and post it on Facebook'

Comment: Use the Feed or the Share Dialog, then you get the preview as a built-in feature.